# React Native/Flexbox align Text bottom right inline with other Text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, native

I'm trying to design a Message Bubble like this:

[image: Telegram Message Bubble]

> Source: Telegram iOS App

Where the Message itself is a `<Text>` component, and the timestamp `<Text>` is nested inside the Message's `<Text>`:

```
  return (
    <MessageBubble {...props}>
      <Text style={fontStyle}>
        {message.text}
        <Text style={timestampStyle}>
          {message.timestamp}
        </Text>
      </Text>
    </MessageBubble>
  );
```

The above code looks like this:

[image: My code]

As you can see, the timestamp renders immediately at the end of the message content, but I want it to align at the bottom right.

I tried to set `timestampStyle` to `alignSelf: 'flex-end'`, `flex: 1`, `flexGrow: 1`, etc but it didn't render at the bottom right.

> Note: I don't want to use `position: 'absolute'` since that would like this:

[image: UI fail]

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve the style of the Telegram message bubble with React Native's Flexbox system?

Comment: `Text` timestamp component may be an inline element, that's why you are getting this. Change its `display` property to `block`.